Is every finite plane with a characteristic Desarguesian?
By a projective plane I understand a mathematical structure $(X,\mathcal L)$ consisting of a set $X$ of points and a family $\mathcal L$ of subsets of $X$, called lines such that the following four axioms are satisfied:

for every distinct points $x,y\in X$, there exists a unique line $L\in\mathcal L$ such that $x,y\in L$;

for every distinct lines $L,\Lambda\in X$, there exists a unique point $x\in X$ such that $x\in L\cap\Lambda$;

every line $L\in\mathcal L$ contains at least three distinct points;

$X\notin\mathcal L$.


It can be shown that every two lines in a projective plane have the same number of points. The order of a projective plane $(X,\mathcal L)$ is the number of points on a line minus $1$. It is well-known that every projective plane of finite order $n$ contains exactly $n^2+n+1$ points and $n^2+n+1$ lines.
A subset $Q\subseteq X$ of a projective plane $(X,\mathcal L)$ is called a quadrangle if $|Q|=4$ and $|L\cap Q|\le 2$ for any line $L\in\mathcal L$.
Let $(X,\mathcal L)$ be a projective plane. A subset $\Pi\subseteq X$ is called a subplane of $(X,\mathcal L)$ if $\Pi$ endowed with the family of lines $\mathcal L_\Pi=\{L\cap \Pi:L\in\mathcal L,\;|\Pi\cap L|\ge 2\}$ is a projective plane.
Definition: A projective plane $(X,\mathcal L)$ is defined to have characteristic $p\in\mathbb N$ if every quadrangle $Q\subseteq X$ is contained in a subplane $\Pi\subseteq X$ of order $p$.
I am interested in the current status of the following known old open
Problem: Is every finite projective plane of prime characteristic Desarguesian?
In his textbook "Projective Planes" (on page 83), Stevenson writes that "for finite planes the answer is unknown". But the book of Stevenson appeared in 1972, so is more than 50 years old. Maybe some progress has been made for those 50 years?
The only positive result in this direction I know is the old Gleason's Theorem of 1956 saying that every finite projective plane of characteristic $2$ is Desarguesian.
What can be said about finite projective planes of characteristic $3$, $5$, and so on?
A known (unproven) conjecture of Hanna Neumann says that every finite non-Desarguesian plane contains a subplane of order $2$. This conjecture of Hanna Heumann implies that every finite projective plane of odd characteristic is Desarguesian. Since no counterexamples of Hanna Neumann's conjecture was found so far, also no examples of non-Desarguesian finite planes with a prime characteristic are known. So, the only hope is to find some (partial) affirmative answer to the Problem.
In this respect I have found that in her Bachelor Thesis "Relationships Between Geometric Propositions which Characterise Projective Planes" Anne Linehan writes in Example 4.3.2 that every finite projective plane with a characteristic is Desarguesian. Unfortunately, she does not give any references to this non-trivial fact. Is it true at all, and if yes, where it has been proved and by whom? Please, let me know if you have any information on this problem.
